# what is the size of the iPhone plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to ask a question about the iPhone plist. What is the size of the plist in each iPhone application? Thank you.

Comment: Plists can be used to store anything. There are also text plists and binary plists. Are you referring to any specific kind or purpose of plist?

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn, thank you for your reply. Actually, I want to store a set of object, and each of the object contains about 3 elements (int, time ..). And, would you give me some reference of different type of plist as I am the green of the objective C. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the infos stored in the plist, as it is merely a container format. It's like asking, "*What is the size of a XML file ?*".

Comment: @DarkDust, thank you for your reply. I have an 2000 elements in the array. And each of the element is an object which contains 3 data members. Is it possible to store it?

Comment: Of course, no problem with that. There are even very convenient methods to do so: -[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:] (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:) and +[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:] (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfFile:)

Comment: Only constraint is that every object stored in the array (and arrays/dictionaries contained in that array) have the NSCoding protocol implemented. That's true e.g. for NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSNumber, NSData, ...

Comment: @DarkDust, thank you very much. Is it possible to stored the user-defined object (e.g. book - name, publish, price)?

Comment: Yes, your objects just need to comply to thr NSCoding protocol. Read the reference of NSCoding for details, it's actually pretty easy.